# Get update from last message

Tags: android, mqtt, iot

I'm creating Android application that controls humidifier by using MQTT. How to deal in situation when application starts and needs to get last date humidifier has sent to MQTT server. I don't need all messages. I just need very last ones.

Answer (score 1):

If the sensor publishes messages with the retained bit set to true, then the broker will store the last message and deliver it to any client when they subscribe to the topic.

You can read more details about retained messages on the HiveMQ blog here:

https://www.hivemq.com/blog/mqtt-essentials-part-8-retained-messages/